# Android icons and correct DP size

Tags: android, dpi, android-icons

I am going through the icon size guidelines of android and if I download their icon set on GitHub for each icon I can find the proper folder as following:

- drawable
- 18 dp
- 24 dp
- 36 dp
- 48 dp
- drawable-hdpi
- 18 dp
- 24 dp
- 36 dp
- 48 dp
- ...
  Now I cannot find which DP I should use for specific controls. For example:
- Action Bar/ Toolbar icons should be 32dp but the icon itself 24dp
- Drawer item icons? Not specified. Should be 18dp?
- TextView icons and general icons in view 18dp?
- Button icons? Not specified
- Fab Button icon size? Not specified

Can anybody pointing me to the right resource so that I can properly import the icons for the relative dp size?

Comment: I remember list icons and FAB buttons sizes being properly described in the guidelines.

Comment: Well I am looking from Material Documentation and general Android. So far I found
Action bar icon 32dp the square and 24dp the icon iteself
Notification 18dp but nothing mentioned for navigation drawer and textboxes

Comment: @Raffaeu could you share the link where you found the above details?